# Tthis codes in Windows

Tags: python-3.x

This codes is working on Raspberry, how can I work this codes in Windows?

```
bashCommand = ['mkvpropedit','{}'.format(dosyatam),'--edit','info','--set','title={}'.format(title)]
            process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            output, error = process.communicate()
            print(output)
```

Comment: Do you have `mkvpropedit` installed on Windows?

Comment: Yes. It is installed: C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working:

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import subprocess
import re

neredebu=r'K:\İnenler\filmler\mkvler'
mkvpeexe=r'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit.exe'
tname="netmanyağı"

for kokdizin, altdizinler, dosyalar in os.walk(neredebu):
    for dosya in dosyalar:
        if dosya.endswith('.mkv'):
            #dosya = os.sep.join([kokdizin, dosya])

            isim=re.findall('([\w\d.]*)\.[\d]{4}\.',dosya)[0]
            isim=isim.replace(".", " ")
            yil=re.split('[\w\d.]*\.([\d]{4})\.',dosya)[1]
            title=isim+" - "+yil+" _ netmanyağı"

            dosyayolu=kokdizin
            dosyatam=dosyayolu+"\\"+dosya

            print(isim)
            print(yil)
            print(title)
            print(dosyayolu)
            print(dosyatam)
            print(dosya)

            output = subprocess.run([mkvpeexe, dosyatam, '--edit', 'info', '--set', 'title={}'.format(title)], capture_output=True)
            print(output.stdout.decode())

            output = subprocess.run([mkvpeexe, dosyatam, '--edit','track:a1','--set','name={}'.format(tname)], capture_output=True)
            print(output.stdout.decode())
```